# Alternatives to PyQt in Linux?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I'm trying to install PyQt5.8.2 in 64-bit Linux Mint, using "sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5" and "sudo pip3 install PyQt5", and both keep throwing segmentation fault errors when trying 'python3 main.py' and causes the terminal to 'quit unexpectedly'.

So I'm going forward with a straight Qt GUI build, but would still like to interface it with Python scripts. Are there any packages which PyQt isn't based on, and are known to be stable?

Comment: A segmentation fault in a widely use package usually points to a larger underlying problem in the system. Could be damaged packages or faulty hardware or many other things. Your very first step should be to cold reboot the machine then check `dmesg` for obvious kernel problems.

Comment: Without knowing what you are trying to run (e.g the contents of main.py and associated files) no one can offer debugging help. Asking for software package recommendations is also considered offtopic for stack overflow. Rather than trying to find a replacement, I suggest you debug why your application segfaults.